typeorm inheritance of tree entities
Hi I have the following abstract TreeEntity
@Tree('closure-table')
@Entity()
export abstract class TreeNodeEntity<T extends TreeNodeEntity<T>> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: TreeNodeType, default: null })
  type: TreeNodeType;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  order: number;

  @Column({ default: null })
  content: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId?: string;

  @TreeParent()
  parent?: T;

  @TreeChildren()
  children?: T[];

  constructor(partial: Partial<TreeNodeEntity<T>>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

And here is my CourseNodeEntity that inherits it:

@Entity()
export class CourseNodeEntity extends TreeNodeEntity<CourseNodeEntity> {
  @Column({ default: false })
  isFree: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => FileEntity, (attachment) => attachment.courseNodeAttachments)
  attachments?: FileEntity[];

  @OneToOne(() => FileEntity)
  @JoinColumn()
  video?: FileEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => CourseEntity, (target) => target.nodes)
  target: CourseEntity;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  homeworksCount: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CourseNodeEntity>) {
    super(partial);
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}


Unfortunately there is an error when I'm trying to add a CourseNode with non-null parentId (
inserting or modifying on table 'course_node_entity' foreign key violation 'FK_15887c4f37b41f4b23d5bc6ac2b'):

Any ideas how to make it works or inheritance will not work with Tree entities and relations in general?
Problem seems to be related to this parentId contraint which normally is course_node_entity but with inheritance is tree_node_entity. How to fix that?

